# Как рассчитать расстояние от одного адреса до другого

Tags: javascript, html, yandex-maps-api, google-maps-api

Заказчик хочет сделать на сайте калькулятор вида: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираешь город, вводишь 2 адреса и калькулятор подсчитывает километраж. Как это можно реализовать?И вообще реально-ли это?

Comment: Возможно конечно. Думаю даже проще чем кажется)

Comment: Хорошо. А как именно?

Comment: Расстояние по прямой или по дороге?

Answer (score 1):

Если заказчик готов отображать данные на карте, то можно получить адрес с помощью саджеста https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/suggest , построить маршрут на карте воспользовавшись примером https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/multiroute_data_access и получить длину маршрута.

Если без карты, то второй пункт меняется на http запрос, о котором можно почитать тут:  https://tech.yandex.ru/routing/router/?from=mapsapi

Comment: Второй пункт предполагает ежегодную оплату?

Comment: Да, предполагает.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще реально. Наверное, интерфейс будет всё-таки отличаться, поскольку и Яндекс Карты и Google Maps требуют указывать адреса вместе с городом.

Вам потребуется API геокодирования, вот, например [Google Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro). Вы отправляете запрос, содержащий адрес, и сервис возвращает вам координаты.

Затем, с помощью, например, [формулы гаверсинусов](https://medium.com/@congyuzhou/%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BB%D0%B8-a398352bfbde) вы вычисляете расстояние между двумя точками, заданными своими координатами.

В данном случае речь о вычислении наименьшего расстояния, то есть длины дуги, соединяющей две точки. Если речь о построении маршрута, то здесь вам поможет [Direction API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/start). Google или Яндекс умеют строить несколько маршрутов сразу, их длина может быть различной.

Answer (score 0):

Все гораздо проще... Качаем базу [КЛАДР](https://kladr-rf.ru/) из [официальных источников](https://fias.nalog.ru/Updates). Ну а расстояние между двумя координатами вычисляются по формуле.

Кратчайшее расстояние между двумя точками на земной поверхности (если принять ее за сферу) определяется зависимостью:

```
 cos(d) = sin(φА)·sin(φB) + cos(φА)·cos(φB)·cos(λА − λB),
```

где φА и φB — широты, λА, λB — долготы данных пунктов, d — расстояние между пунктами, измеряемое в радианах длиной дуги большого круга земного шара.

Расстояние между пунктами, измеряемое в километрах, определяется по формуле:

```
L = d·R,
```

где R = 6371 км — средний радиус земного шара.

Справочные данные:

- Средний радиус Земли R = 6371210 м.
- Экваториальный радиус Земли RЭ = 6378,245 м.
- Полярный радиус Земли RП = 6356,830 м.
- Длина дуги меридиана (дуги экватора, дуги окружности большого круга) в 1°, 1′ и 1″ равна соответственно:

  - 111 197 м (111,2 км),
  - 1852 м (1,852 км) и
  - 30,9 м.